# Need help doing a one-to-many relationship with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Here are the mappings for my objects:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTest"
                   namespace="NHibernateTest.Database">
    <class name="Employer">
        <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTest"
                   namespace="NHibernateTest.Database">
    <class name="Employee">    
        <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="FirstName"/>
        <property name="LastName"/>
        <property name="Email"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here are the objects themselves:

```
namespace NHibernateTest.Database {
    public class Employee {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employer {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the SchemaExport utility to generate the schema, but cannot figure out how to write the mapping for the `IList`. It's  been a long time since I've touched Hibernate for Java and am finding the documentation on one-to-many for NHibernate to be a bit difficult to follow. If someone could write that mapping, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: What are the names of the respective tables and what field in the Employee table is the Employer.Id foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess the name of the Employee table and the Employer.Id foreign key but here's how I would do it:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTest"
                   namespace="NHibernateTest.Database">
    <class name="Employer">
        <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name"/>
        <bag name="Employees" table="Employees" >
            <key column="EmployerId"></key>
            <one-to-many class="Employee"></one-to-many>
       </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTest"
                   namespace="NHibernateTest.Database">
    <class name="Employee">    
        <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="id" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="EmployerId" />
        <property name="FirstName"/>
        <property name="LastName"/>
        <property name="Email"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here's the .net code:

```
namespace NHibernateTest.Database {
    public class Employee {
        public Employee(Employer employer) { EmployerId = employer.Id; }
        protected Employee() {} // nHibernate needs access to a parameterless constructor.
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        protected virtual long EmployerId { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employer {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to others who see this, I had to add cascade="all" to the bag tag in order to make it work.